# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

So I have this code:

```
    public int saleCount(List<Shift> shifts) {
        var query = (
            from x in database.ItemSales
            where shifts.Any(y => y.ID == x.shiftID)
            select x.SalesCount
        );
        return query.Sum();
    }
```

Unfortunately, it's throwing this error:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Shift'. 
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

So here is where I define shift, which is just a normal Entity Framework Code First object:

```
[Table("Shifts")]
public class Shift : MPropertyAsStringSettable {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public string ShiftID_In_POS { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftDate { get; set; }
}
```

I guess the problem is that I am using Shift object in a Linq query.  And I am doing a "Any" operation on a List of "Shift".

One possible solution is to change the List to maybe a Collection or something, afterall, I am loading it with a linq query somewhere else, but what would the signature be?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this change that does not use a collection of `Shift`s in the query:

```
public int saleCount(List<Shift> shifts) {
    var shiftIds = shifts.Select(s => s.ID).ToList();
    var query = (
        from x in database.ItemSales
        where shiftIds.Contains(x.shiftID)
        select x.SalesCount
    );
    return query.Sum();
}
```

The idea is to avoid passing `Shift` objects to the query provider, using IDs instead.

Comment: Yup!  Worked well, I was going to suggest to change the List to some other type of collection, but this is great.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error because

```
bool isPresent = entities.VaccinationRecords.Any(id => id.PersonId.equals(studetails.StuId));
```

personID and StuId is INT type , but I am using .equals to compare both values.

Then i have done this;

```
bool isPresent = entities.VaccinationRecords.Any(id => id.PersonId == studetails.StuId);
```

Issue resolved.