# Linq Contains with array of enum

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, entity-framework, enums

I want to return a list of tickets which are currently in one of the given statuses. There's an array of the enum TicketState (with values Open, InProgress and Finished).

```
public IEnumerable<Ticket> ReadTickets(TicketState[] states)
{
    return ctx.Tickets.Where(t => states.Contains(t.State)).AsEnumerable();   
}
```

The following exception appears when I test the method:

> Cannot compare elements of type 'Project.BL.Domain.Ticketing.TicketState[]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

I've tried to make a list from the array and to use an array of bytes instead, but I keep getting exceptions.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile - `states.Contains(t.State)` isn't a delegate or an expression tree type... Now we could *guess* that you've just missed out `state =>` but who knows what other changes there are...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615803/only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-types-are-supported-in-this-context, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211362/only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-types-are-supported-in-this-context, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592042/linq-to-entities-only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-types-are-supported-error, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379394/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-exception, try searching. EF can't translate that LINQ to an SQL query. Which EF version is this? How is `Ticket.State` declared?

Comment: @JonSkeet, `Contains` can definitely receive a single `T` and check for its existence. No need for delegate or expression.

Comment: @haim770 there's shorthand for `(t => Foo(t))` as `(Foo)`, but not like OP had.

Comment: @haim770: Look at version 1 of the question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for [Enumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx)?

```
return ctx.Tickets.Where(t => states.Any(s => t.State == s)).AsEnumerable();
```