# Compare the int values from enum list

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, contains

Having this enum :

```
public enum MyEnums
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3,
    D = 4,
    E = 5
}
```

If I create a list with some enum values from MyEnums for example this :

```
IEnumerable<MyEnums> myEnums = new(){ MyEnums.A, MyEnums.B, MyEnums.C };
```

How can I check that a int value is in this list?

```
query.Where(x => myEnums.Contains((int)x.MyValue));
```

The problem is that the name of 'x.MyValue' is not the same then the name in 'MyEnums' only the int value is the same.

Comment: You seem to be using Linq - is this for Linq-to-Objects (in-memory), or Linq-to-Entities (Entity Framework / Entity Framework Core?) - or some other Linq provider?

Comment: Linq-to-Entities, 'x.MyValue' is coming from the database. using EF Core.

Comment: Did you see [Linq Contains with array of enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31179649/3744182)?  Does that work for you?

Comment: @dbc, tried that but it returns all records it doesn't filter out the records where 'x.MyValue' is in myEnums.

Comment: query.Where(x => myEnums.Any(y => x.MyValue == (int)y)).AsEnumerable()

Comment: 1) Can you share a [mcve]?  Specifically, how is `x.MyValue` declared?  Is it an integer, or a `MyEnums`?  2) What version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: If `x.MyValue` is an `int`, and I declare `myEnums` as an array of integers not an array of enums, then `query.Where(x => myEnums.Any(y => x.MyValue == y)).AsEnumerable()` works with LINQ to Objects, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/kceYv5.  Similarly, if both `x.MyValue` is a `MyEnum` and `myEnums` is a `MyEnum` array, then the query works with LINQ to Objects, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/XqI6LN.

Comment: @dbc Yeah but that gives you `O(n*m)` perf (especially if `myEnums` contains  more than a handful of items) - a better approach would be to convert the predicate to a range-check or even a HashSet if necessary.

Comment: @Dai - With LINQ to Objects that's true for sure, but with LINQ to Entities would the provider or database itself do the `.Any()` optimization automatically?  That's not a rhetorical question BTW, I actually don't know how that gets implemented by the DB provider.

Comment: @dbc EF and EFC for SQL Server converted `.Contains` expressions into `WHERE x IN ( a, b, c )`-type SQL predicate (which is identical to `WHERE ( x = a OR x = b OR x = c )`), which works okay for most cases, but when the set varies it means an explosion of new query-execution-plans - so in EF Core 7 (or 8? I forget) they added support for changing the query to use an `INNER JOIN` against a TVP.

Comment: @Dai - interesting thanks.  Rereading the question, I wonder if I have misunderstood the problem?  The final sentence reads *The problem is that the name of 'x.MyValue' is not the same then the name in 'MyEnums' only the int value is the same.*  I wonder if the querent is actually saying that `x.MyValue` is actually a **completely different enum type** and needs to compare its int value with the int value of `MyEnums` for some reason?  If so, we really do need a [mcve].

Comment: If `x.MyValue` is an `int`, I believe you can try something like `.Where(x => myEnums.Select(e => (int)e).Contains(x.MyValue))`. The select converts the `IEnumerable<MyEnums>` to an `IEnumerable<int>` and the resulting SQL should be the equivalent of `WHERE x.MyValue IN (1, 2, 3)`.  If that doesn't translate directly, you might need to map the enum values separately with `List<int> MyEnumInts = myEnums.Select(e => (int)e).toList();` and then use `.Where(x => myEnumInts.Contains(x.MyValue))`.

Answer (score 0):

If the collection of values has a property that is an `int` value, then you can use the fact that an `enum` is actually an `int` under the hood. It isn't clear exactly what you want, so here are a few possibilities (and I create a collection of simple objects to show):

1. You want to get a collection of the `int` values that are defined by the `enum`:

```
public enum MyEnum {A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5}

public class ExampleType {
    public int MyValue { get; set;} 
}

public static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnums = new List<MyEnum>(){ MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C };
    IEnumerable<ExampleType> query = new List<ExampleType>(){ new ExampleType(){MyValue = 1}, new ExampleType(){MyValue = 2}, new ExampleType(){MyValue = 9}};
    var results = query.Where(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), x.MyValue)).Select(x => x.MyValue);
    foreach (var r in results) {
        Console.WriteLine(r);   
    }
}
```

The result is {1, 2}

2. You want to get a collection of the `enum` values that are defined by the `enum` that happen to be in the collection of `int` values:

```
public enum MyEnum {A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5}

public class ExampleType {
    public int MyValue { get; set;} 
}

public static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnums = new List<MyEnum>(){ MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C };
    IEnumerable<ExampleType> query = new List<ExampleType>(){ new ExampleType(){MyValue = 1}, new ExampleType(){MyValue = 2}, new ExampleType(){MyValue = 9}};
    var results = query.Where(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), x.MyValue)).Select(x => (MyEnum)x.MyValue);
    foreach (var r in results) {
        Console.WriteLine(r);   
    }
}
```

The result is {A, B}

3. You want to get a collection of `ExampleType` objects that have an `int` value for a property that is defined by the `enum`:

```
public enum MyEnum {A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5}

public class ExampleType {
    public int MyValue { get; set;} 
    
    public override string ToString() {
        return this.MyValue.ToString();
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnums = new List<MyEnum>(){ MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C };
    IEnumerable<ExampleType> query = new List<ExampleType>(){ new ExampleType(){MyValue = 1}, new ExampleType(){MyValue = 2}, new ExampleType(){MyValue = 9}};
    var results = query.Where(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), x.MyValue));
    foreach (var r in results) {
        Console.WriteLine(r);   
    }
}
```

The result is two `ExampleType` objects that have `MyValue` property values that are valid values defined by `MyEnum`.